# find files within a time range plus one additional file

Tags: linux, bash

I need to get some files picked up in a time range plus one file more with linux board tools like "find".

Let me give an example: I need all files modified between "2018-06-06 10:27:24" and "2018-06-06 16:43:47" and one file created after that timestamp. My problem is. I only get the information about these two timestamps and the next file created after the second timestamp could be created at any time. one minute or one week after the second timestamp.

My most elegant try was something like:

`find /FOLDER -name "*MYPATTERN*" -newermt "2018-06-06 10:27:24" ! -newermt "2018-06-06 16:43:47"`

But with this solution there is no plus one additional file and I cannot find a nice solution so far.

Best regards
neik

Answer (score 0):

perhaps in two steps

```
$ find ... -newermt "{latest_timestamp}" -printf "%TY%Tm%Td%TH%TM%TS\t%p\n" | 
  sort -nr | awk -F'\t' '{print $2; exit}'
```

will give you one file updated after the latest_timestamp.

Or, instead of manually setting the date/time to be sortable numerically just use `%@T` as suggested by @Socowi in the comments.

Comment: Just use `%T@` as the date format. Makes sorting very simple. In addition, I would write the filename after the date, so that spaces in the filename can be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Add an "or" clause to your current find command:

```
t1="2018-06-06 10:27:24"
t2="2018-06-06 16:43:47"

find /FOLDER \( -name "*MYPATTERN*" -newermt "$t1" ! -newermt "$t2" \) \
          -o \( -name '*THE_EXTRA_FILE*' -newermt "$t2" \)
```